# App is not closing during appium session in Simulator

Tags: ios, automation, appium, simulator, close-application

Failed to close app in simulator at the time of mobile test execution

Tried driver.closeApp() command . Also tried exit with code Zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Appium Session is running a default capability is passed in logs.
check in logs **shouldTerminatApp** if it is false.

In the base class mention the following:

DesiredCapabilities dc= new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.dc.setCapability("shouldTerminateApp",true);